# Alternate between subtracting and adding array items

Tags: javascript, pi

I'm trying to create a formula for calculating PI using the [Gregory-Leibniz series](https://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Pi). I've created a for loop that's populating a new array with the individual values, but I need a way to then alternate between subtracting and adding each array item and then spit out the resulting number. Essentially, I need to get to something like this:

(4/1) - (4/3) + (4/5) - (4/7) + (4/9) - (4/11) + (4/13) - (4/15)

The following for loop is populating the new array correctly:

```
var arrLimit = 39; 
var newArray = [];

for(i = 1; i <= arrLimit; i += 2) {     
    newArray.push(4/i);
}
```

At this point I get stuck. I need some way to take newArray and alternate between subtracting and adding the values, and then produce the final number.

Comment: That link is missing the most fun way to calculate pi. Throw darts at a unit square and count how many land in the upper right quadrant of a unit circle: https://jsfiddle.net/0crLyswx/ . Each dart has a `pi/4` of landing in the circle, so you can easily estimate pi from the result and if you want more accuracy, throw more darts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sum your array with reduce, then judge *=-1 or *=1 based on the index of the array.

The code will be like below:

```js
//Test Case 1
var arrLimit = 39; 
var newArray = [];

for(i = 1; i <= arrLimit; i += 2) {     
    newArray.push(4/i);
}

console.log(newArray.reduce(function(pre, cur, currentIndex){
  return pre+cur*(currentIndex%2 ? -1 : 1);
  }, 0));

//Test Case 2
arrLimit = 11139; 
newArray = [];
for(i = 1; i <= arrLimit; i += 2) {     
    newArray.push(4/i);
}
console.log(newArray.reduce(function(pre, cur, currentIndex){
  return pre+cur*(currentIndex%2 ? -1 : 1);
  }, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep an extra variable, `isNeg = true`.  On each iteration of the loop, just alternate it with `isNeg = !isNeg;`.

```
var arrLimit = 39; 
var newArray = [];
var isNeg = false;

for(i = 1; i <= arrLimit; i += 2) {     
    isNeg = !isNeg;
    var val = 4/i;
    if (isNeg) {
        val *= -1;
    }
    newArray.push(val);
}
```

You can also assign 1 to the variable, and multiple it by -1 each time to do the flip:

```
var arrLimit = 39; 
var newArray = [];
var factor = 1;

for(i = 1; i <= arrLimit; i += 2) {     
    factor *= -1;
    var val = factor * 4 / i;
    newArray.push(val);
}
```

Personally I favor the second approach, but both work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an extra variable. If you want you could sum at the same time.

```
  var arrLimit = 39; 
  var newArray = [];
  var a=-1
  var sum =0
  for(i = 1; i <= arrLimit; i += 2) { 
      a*=-1;
      newArray.push(a*4/i);
      sum+=a*4/i
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need some way to take newArray and alternate between subtracting and adding the values, and then produce the final number.

You can do that with [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
// Your code, unchanged
var arrLimit = 39; 
var newArray = [];

for(i = 1; i <= arrLimit; i += 2) {     
    newArray.push(4/i);
}

// reduce the array to the final result
// (2*(-i%2)+1) alternates between `-1` and `1`.
var result = newArray.reduce( (prev,curr,i) => prev + (2*(-i%2)+1)*curr );
console.log( result );
```

Comment: This way `(2*(-i%2)+1)*curr` is smart.

Comment: Thanks, FYI you can also leave off the initial value of `0` for the reduce since when there is one element that is the result you want and when there are 2 elements using the first element as `prev` is correct. The only case where it is different without the initial value is for an empty array (an error is thrown instead of resulting in `0`)

Answer (score 0):

How about doing away with the array in the first place and being able to "calculate" pi with as many terms as you like.

```js
let pi = 0,
    terms = 100;

for (var i = 0; i < terms; i++){
  pi += 4/(2*i + 1) * ( i % 2 == 0 ? 1 : -1)
}

console.log(pi);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the length of `newArray` when you build it and multiply the value by -1 or +1

```js
var arrLimit = 39; 
var newArray = [];

for(i = 1; i <= arrLimit; i += 2) {   
  newArray.push(4 / i * (newArray.length % 2 ? 1 : -1));
}

console.log(newArray);
```